# Get inserted ids of multiple insert statements

Tags: mysql, node.js

Via conncetion with `multipleStatements: true` I execute multiple `insert` statements like that:

```
connection.query(`
  INSERT INTO posts SET ?;
  INSERT INTO posts SET ?;
`, [{title: 'Test #1'}, {title: 'Test #2'}], function(err, result) {
  // How to get both new ids here?
});
```

I've [found](//stackoverflow.com/a/31371153/4928642) how to do it with single statement, but don't know how to use it with multiple.

Also I tried to add `SELECT LAST_INSERTED_ID();` into query, but got

> Error Code: 1305. FUNCTION qqq.LAST_INSERTED_ID does not exist

where `qqq` is shema name.

PS: Real query also contains other statements (`update` and `delete`), not only inserts.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, mysql-5.5.50-win32 and `mysql` npm packadge. But query with `LAST_INSERTED_ID` I checked directly in mysql-workbench-community-6.3.7-winx64.

Comment: The function is `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, not `LAST_INSERTED_ID()`.

Comment: @Solarflare, it works, thanks. Will you post it as an answer?